# Picks out those elements of raw of matrix for which the corresponding element of vector is True.

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, complex-analysis, definition

I want to define a mathematical definition for this process

Illustrative example, consider the matrix $A$

> $A=\left( \begin{array}{ccccc}  1 & 0   \\  0 & 1  \\  1 & 1  
>  \\ \end{array} \right)$
>   and 
>   $V=(1,0,1)$

I suppose

$$B=A^T=(r_1,r_2,r_3)^T$$

Then $B=((1,0),(0,1),(1,1))$.
I need to pick  the row of matrix $B$ iff the corresponding element of vector $V$ is $1$ $($one$)$. Then we get
$$Pick_B=\{(1,0),(1,1)\}$$

Is it a mathematical formulation of this process. Or a better mathematical expression. I needed help writing the text for this definition in mathematical form. Can you help me formulate a definition in general.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understood correctly, but if you need to pick the rows of $B=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\ 0& 1\\ 1& 1\end{pmatrix}$ corresponding to the positions of the numbers $1$ within the vector $V=(1,0,1)$, you can do the following.

Define the matrix
$N(V)=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0\\  0&0& 1\end{pmatrix}$ (There is only one 1 on each row and the rows add up to V)  then the rows of $N(V)B=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\  1& 1\end{pmatrix}$ are the the required rows.

Comment: How did you build the matrix $N(V)$

Comment: Hi @Emadkareem . The idea is to split $V$ in many rows such that each row has only one 1. The numbers 1s in N(V) must occupy the same columns of the 1s in $V$, but in different rows.

Answer (score 1):

As @Daniel wrote, it suffices to construct $N(V)$ where $V=[v_1,\cdots,v_n]^T$

"$\textbf{.}$" denotes the Hadamard product.

Step 1. $(V[1,\cdots,1])\textbf{.} I_n=diag(v_1,\cdots,v_n)$.

step 2. remove the zero rows of the previous result. This is a job for logical indexing. I don't think that there exist standard non-logical operations that do the job.

EDIT. An example. Let $V=[a,0,b,0]^T$, where $a,b\not= 0$.

Step 1. Let $D=(V[1,1,1,1])\textbf{.}I_4=\begin{pmatrix}a&a&a&a\\0&0&0&0\\b&b&b&b\\0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}\textbf{.}I_4=diag(a,0,b,0)$.

step 2. For every zero diagonal entry of $D$, we remove the row where it stands, that is  $N(V)=\begin{pmatrix}a&0&0&0\\0&0&b&0\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: A special idea ... Can you explain to me a simplified example ... grateful to you